# Which controller is triggered by widget?

Tags: angularjs

I have a small angular application which was written by a third party and I need to rearrange its layout (e.g. move a search form from the main body to the top menu bar).

Is there a way to determine which controller is triggered when a widget is active? Digging through source is OK and I'm doing it right now. However, I'd prefer something along the lines of a debug message

> Widget [widget id] triggered [controller id]

Comment: Check for ng-controller attribute in html for given section

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar yes, that's the manual approach. I'm wondering if there's an automated way (I've updated the question accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to figure out the controller:

1. Check the ng-controller directive in the said HTML.
2. If you are using ng-route, then find the page URL in your code. Controller class can be defined when specifying routes.

Hope this helps.